# Changing absolute paths htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, structure, markup

Is there a way you can change the absolute path in the .htaccess?

For example when I am working on my local server my url is something like this:

> localhost:8888/websites/sitename/

When I use an absolute path like: /assets/css/style.css, it will look for it at:

> localhost:8888/assets/css/style.css

but I need it to look in:

> localhost:8888/websites/sitename/assets/css/style.css

Comment: When writing AJAX calls I don't want to write out relative paths that may change on the live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done by setting up a vhost on your local machine, not via the .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/websites/sitename%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /websites/sitename/$1 [L]
```